# Django: how to use settings in templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Django: how to use settings in templates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass settings to a template like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'settings': settings},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template:

```
{{ settings.MY_SETTING_NAME }}
```

If you need to access your settings in many templates (many views), consider creating an appropriate [template context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).

Comment: If you don't need everything from the settings file, it might be better to import the individual settings you need access to

Answer (score 2):

If using a class-based view:

```
#
# in settings.py
#
YOUR_CUSTOM_SETTING = 'some value'

#
# in views.py
#
from django.conf import settings #for getting settings vars

class YourView(DetailView): #assuming DetailView; whatever though

    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(YourView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['YOUR_CUSTOM_SETTING'] = settings.YOUR_CUSTOM_SETTING

        return context

#
# in your_template.html, reference the setting like any other context variable
#
{{ YOUR_CUSTOM_SETTING }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import it.

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple.

Like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

print settings.MY_SETTING_NAME
```